# C#; having trouble passing a variable by reference into a generic linked list

Tags: c#, generics, nullreferenceexception

I have a project where I need to modify the supplied code to do various things with a generic linked list. My issue is that I can not get the variable values to be nodes in the list. I continually get NullReferenceExceptions regardless of the fact that is seems as though I have no null values. Ill post some of the code and what lines its tellling me the problems appear at.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        UnorderedLinkedList<int> u = new UnorderedLinkedList<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("int");
        int var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 12;
        u.print();
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 2;
        u.print();
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 29;
        u.print();
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 5;
        u.print();
        u.insert(ref var);
        u.print();
        var = 5;

    }

namespace LinkedListNamespace
{
public abstract class LinkedList<T>
{
    protected class Node
    { 
        public T value;
        public Node next;

    }

    protected Node start = new Node();


 public LinkedList()
    {
        start = null;  //getting an exception from this line.
    }

}
 public class UnorderedLinkedList<T> : LinkedList<T>, LinkedListADT<T>
{
 public override void insert(ref T item)
    {
        if (start == null)
        {

            start.value = item; //getting an exception from this line as well.
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp;
            for (temp = start; temp.next != null; temp = temp.next)
            {
                temp.next.value = item;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

there is more code i can supply from the project if it helps.

Comment: `if (start == null) start.value = item;` So... if `start` **is null** you try to set `start.value`, well start is null, so you get a null reference exception because you can't set `.value` of a `null` object.

Comment: Null exception is not the only issue in your code. Why are you using `ref`? Do you understand what that means? Read more on that.

Comment: ref was used in the supplied code I am supposed to use. As well as inheritance and abstract classes.

Comment: @S.Dodson: I would seriously question the source of the supplied material then... especially if they used the name `insert` which doesn't follow .NET naming conventions. If this is material you're meant to learn from, I'd question its value - you don't want to build up bad habits. (The public fields are a bad idea too...)

Comment: Yeah you're not the only one questioning the source of the supplied material. Others working on the same project are too. Just hoping now that my work on this doesn't screw me over later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I humbly suggest that you don't understand what ref is doing. It certainly gives a misleading API. You have 5 lines saying

u.Insert(ref var);

This API design using 'ref' would make the caller believe that These are all inserting the same reference into the list, i.e. a reference to the variable called var. Changing the value of var in between is irrelevant.

The null reference exception from

start.value = item;

Should be obvious because that line is only executed if 'start' is null. Just in case it's not obvious: if "start" is null, then you can't set properties or call methods on it (that's what a null reference exception is).

EDIT to ADD:
Also, you're going to have to give us more of a clue than just saying...

start = null;  //getting an exception from this line.

what is the exception?

Comment: *These are all inserting the same reference into the list* This code do not insert reference into the list. Although `insert` take its argument by reference, is then assign field `value` by value.

Comment: im sorry, the exception is a null reference exception

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks, I have edited to clarify my concern over the design of the API using 'ref'.

Comment: @S.Dodson "start = null;" can't give you a null reference exception because there is nothing on this line which is trying to dereference a pointer. Please check what exception it was, and let us know.

Comment: I have made some edits after reading the comments here and I am now getting a list produced with ints, doubles, and strings thank you